# Cannot open file with fopen(); function - C Programing

Tags: c, linux

1. I am trying to create a program that using the `fopen();` function.
2. My problem is that `fopen();` cannot find the file.

   - when i am using `perror("Error");` the output is `Error: No such file or directory.`
3. I have read this articles and they did`not solved my problem:

   - [fopen() returning a NULL pointer, but the file definitely exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686318/fopen-returning-a-null-pointer-but-the-file-definitely-exists/26604190)
   - [Unable to open a file with fopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746510/unable-to-open-a-file-with-fopen)
   - It means i have tried to use `fopen();` with the exec path to the file, and i have checked that the filename is the specific filename that i am looking for.
   - I have also used `exec("pwd");` to see that i am the correct directory.
4. My OS is ubuntu mate 20.04.
5. Here is my Code:

   ```
   /* File Name: firstTransaction.c 
    * File Mission: scan the input files and make the first transaction.
    */

   #include "defines.h"

   /*
    * first transaction file:
    * Allocating new memory for the assembly source file.
    * Scanning the assembly source file.
    * @param filename - the filename of the file that needs to be converted by the program.
    * @return output and files -
    *      output the assembly source file in a machine code.
    *      return extern, entry and object files.
    */

   /* function prototype */

   extern char * readText(FILE * ptr, long ic, long dc); /* the function defined on assistanceFunctions.c file */

   int firstTransaction(int * cf, char **av)
   {
       FILE * fp; /* a pointer for fopen function */
       char * filteredFile = NULL;
       long ic = 100, dc = 0; /* declaration and initialization of the instruction counter and current data counter */
       int i = 0, j = 0; /* indexes */
       int cfh = 0; /* compatible file holder */
       int fileNameLength = (int)strlen(av[i]); /* computing the first filename length to allocate memory */
       char * fileName = (char*) calloc(fileNameLength,sizeof (char)); /* allocating memory for the first filename */
       system("pwd");
       while(cf[i] != 0) /* while there is more compatible files to open */
       {
       cfh = cf[i]; /* cfh - compatible file holder, cf - compatible file array, set the next compatible file to cfh */
       strcpy(fileName,av[cfh]); /* copy the file name from the argv array */
       fp = fopen("fileName","r"); /* open the first compatible file for read */
       if(fp == NULL) /* if file does not exists */
       {
           perror("Error"); /* print the error - why the file not opened */
           i++; /* increment i by one and try to open the next filename */
       }else /* if the file was opened successfully, start scanning the file */
       {
           /*filteredFile = */ readText(fp, ic, dc); /* calling readText function with pointer to the start of the file that was opend by fopen function */
          /* while(filteredFile[j] != EOF)
               {
                   putchar(filteredFile[j]);
                   j++;
               }
           /* DONT FORGET TO CLOSE WITH FCLOSE(); */
       }
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

**Here is some screenshots with the tested solutions that failed from the other articles:**

[image: triedSolutions]

**Edited after NeonFire answers:**

1. My first code used `fp = fopen(fileName,"r");` but my error message was made manually this way: `printf("error, %s file does not exists\n", fileName); /* print error message to the user */`

   - this cause that i did`not find my real error.
   - then i changed to `fp = fopen("fileName","r");` and used `perror("Error");` instead of the first and right way.
   - after i read NeonFire answers i got a new error Error: Too many open files.
   - i removed the backups file from the directory and i still have the same error.

**Edited after Ted Lyngmo comment:**
i did had to close the file to solve the - "to many file to open error".

Comment: your ```fp = fopen("fileName","r");``` is incorrect. Remove the quotes from fileName so it refers to  your variable ```char * fileName``` , not a string ```"fileName"```

Comment: @NeonFire Make it into an answer. Would get my vote.

Comment: @TedLyngmo simple mistakes always get the best of us!

Comment: I think that the OP might well have discovered the root cause if they'd made more of an effort to reduce this code down to a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: What does "_Here is some screenshots with the tested solutions that failed from the other articles:_" have to do with the original question? **One** question per question please.

Comment: The _backups_ do not have anything to do with this. You open a lot of files but you don't close them so ... "_Too many open files_" is the result. `fclose` each `FILE*` when you're done with it.

Comment: "Here is some screenshots" Please do not add screenshots of plain text. Instead just copy&paste into your question.

Comment: `calloc(fileNameLength,` That is not enough to hold the terminating 0 byte. Also in C it is not needed to cast result of `malloc`, `calloc` etc..

Comment: You don't  allocate enough memory to hold the filename string. Remember that strings are zero-terminated.  You also assume that  no filenames are longer than the first one when doing `strcpy`. And the allocated memory is never freed.  In your case you don't need to mess with `calloc`/`strcpy`/`free`. Just let `fileName` point to the same strings as `av[cfh]`, like this:  `fileName = av[cfh];`

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your comment, i am aware to this issues, i stopped editing the code while getting the question errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your `fp = fopen("fileName","r");` is incorrect. Remove the quotes from fileName so it refers to your variable `char * fileName` , not a string `"fileName"` :)

Comment: hi there and thanks for your answer! i first tried with `fileName` without quotes but the error message was made by me with `printf();` function, that's why i didn't noticed the other error that i have which seems to be "Error: Too many open files", i have a backups directory that contains all the files that i have in the parent directory, ill try to delete now the backups file, maybe it is trying to read Recursively.

Comment: @CrazyTux That's an unrelated issue and you have a hint in your own code `DONT FORGET TO CLOSE WITH FCLOSE();` (it should be `fclose(FILE*);` but close enough)  - However, this answer answers your question about not being able to open the file.